# jquery problem how to perform the function when button will clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGcjp.png)

**html code**

```
<nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block" >
        <ul> 
      
     @foreach($get_section as $section)    
          <li class="drop-down"><a href="{{$section['section_url']}}">{{$section['name']}}</a>
          <ul>

     @foreach($section['categories'] as $category)       
              <li class="@if(!empty($category['sub_category']))drop-down @endif"><a href="{{url($category['url'])}}">{{$category['category_name']}}</a>
                <ul>
     @foreach($category['sub_category'] as $sub_cate)             
                  <li>
                    <a href="/services/web_development">{{$sub_cate['category_name']}}</a>
                  </li>
     @endforeach             
                </ul>
              </li>
     @endforeach         
              
            </ul>
          </li> 
    @endforeach       
                                
<li id="navbar"><a  href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login"> admin Login </a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;

{{--<li id="navbar"><a  href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login"> <i class="flaticon-padlock"> </i> customer Login </a></li>--}}
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

**javascript code**

```
if ($('.nav-menu').length) {
    var $mobile_nav = $('.nav-menu').clone().prop({
      class: 'mobile-nav d-lg-none' //mobile nav class
    });
    $('body').append($mobile_nav);
    $('body').prepend('<button type="button" class="mobile-nav-toggle d-lg-none"><i class="icofont-navigation-menu"></i></button>');
    $('body').append('<div class="mobile-nav-overly"></div>');

    $(document).on('click', '.mobile-nav-toggle', function(e) {
      $('body').toggleClass('mobile-nav-active');
      $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
      $('.mobile-nav-overly').toggle();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.mobile-nav .drop-down > a', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
      var container = $(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle");
      if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
          $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
          $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
          $('.mobile-nav-overly').fadeOut();
        }
      }
    });
  } else if ($(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle").length) {
    $(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle").hide();
  }
```

As shown in the image (mobile version) when the user clicks the admin login button then cross button at the top also clicked simultaneously
so, what should I change in my code to get this functionality